# iOS 13.x didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is never called

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Haven't done iOS dev for long time (iOS 8) so had to read up and started on a new app.
Problem is that I don't get a device token callback. Certificates and profiles are setup correctly

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   var window: UIWindow?


    static var sharedDelegate: AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }

          return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)")
    }




}
```

Problem is that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken or didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError is not called whatever I try.
note: entitlement is correct, Push Notification ability added, even background mode Remote notification is added.

Can someone provide a working app example that prompts for permission and register and prints the deviceToken

Comment: do you try it on a device or simulator? PN's are not supported on simulator

Comment: It was on iPhone and iPad both no success

Comment: What happens if you just call `registerForRemoteNotifications`? Authorization is only needed to show them to the user so you can test without it.

Comment: I tried your code in a sample project and it worked fine. do you have anything in the logs when you run the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing it this way. (Sorry, had to post it here as an answer instead of as a comment because of the length restriction and for better formatting)

```swift
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.delegate = self
    // check for user permission first
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, _) in
        NSLog("PUSH NOTIFICATION PERMISSION GRANTED: \(granted)")
        guard granted else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
```

Some more notes:

Maybe a deciding difference could be that I'm using a `let` constant for the `current()` object and storing it rather than assigning the delegate to the `current()`? I think I remember struggling like you do because of that...
By the way, I'm calling this function after enabling a Switch for receiving Notifications, so double-check your function for registering is even called! Maybe another hind could be to call it on `UIApplication.shared` instead of the `application` parameter in `AppDelegate`, but I think that shouldn't make a difference...